# What are you allowed to talk about on here?

Tags: discussion

My question was deleted for asking how long Net Neutrality will take to be put into place once passed. I also wanted a debate on weather net neutrality is a good thing, what exactly it will do to the internet and my opinion.

It was deleted by the community for no reason I can think of. It seems the other people in the politics part of Stack Exchange are starting healthy debates so why was I not allowed to talk about net neutrality? Seems a bit one sided to me? What are you allowed to talk about on here so I don't run into this mistake again and please this time I feel there is no reason to delete my question.

Here was the original question:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/7860/has-net-neutrality-already-taken-place?noredirect=1#comment23950_7860

Comment: These discussions belong on [meta]; I've flagged this for migration. Briefly: SE is not a discussion forum, nor is it a place for debate. It is a question and answer site. More details in the [help/dont-ask], and on the [about] page.

Comment: The last revision of the question is not actually that bad.  It's not a great question, but it's acceptable.  I don't know why it was deleted, but since it was "Community", I assume it was because it was old, closed, and downvoted.  The original form of it was not on topic, for the reasons that everyone else is saying.

Comment: @Bobson What was the last revision, for sub-2k users?

Comment: @cpast - `Should have made this question more clear. Has the FCC started regulating the internet yet? From my understanding the FCC wanted to treat the internet like a utility. Would that then not mean that all fast lanes would be shut down. If YouTube or Facebook had their own fast lanes than it's safe to assume loading times would be slower for them.`  Unlike the first revision, which started `Has anyone been having slower internet lately?`, this has an objective answer.

Comment: "I also wanted a debate" = debate is good, but not what SE was designed for. You'd be better asking that in a discussion forum.

Answer (score 5):

You question wasn't deleted because it was about some sort of banned topic.  It ended up deleted for general low-quality-ness

---

When your question was closed, it looked like this

> Has anyone been having slower internet lately? Problems and such. It's a shame that this has passed. I guess our government doesn't like the free market.

That's not really a question, so it got closed.  Your edit didn't make it too much better.  It's still a single ugly blob of text, and you're kinda asking a hypothetical question, so nobody bothered to reopen it.

It looks like it was deleted by the "Community" user, which normally means that it was automatically deleted by a back end process.  Probably because it was closed, down voted, and didn't have very much activity.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange is a network of Q&A sites. It is not a discussion forum, and discussion and debate is not what questions and answers are for. Answers can *disagree*, to be sure, but they can't just be opinions, nor should they be directly replying to each other.

If you want to have a discussion, chat is a good place for that (note that there's a minimum reputation to use chat), but it doesn't belong in questions and answers. More details can be found in the [help center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. (Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat.)

Read that help center page and the blog posts it links for more detail about the difference between good subjective questions and bad ones. Questions intended to provoke debate are bad ones, because this Q&A-optimized platform is bad at debates.